# TeX Live Utility on Mac OSX error: installing gpg appears to have failed

Tags: installing, update, texlive-2021

I am trying to update my current version of TeX on Mac OS X 10.15.7.  I don't think I've ever updated it before but I was told that to use my [university LaTex thesis template](https://gitlab.com/vigou3/ulthese), I should [install "Tex Live 2021" or update the package using Tex Live Utility](https://gitlab.com/vigou3/ulthese/-/issues/9#note_722976486).

First, I went to https://www.tug.org/texlive/ where it says

> ... for MacOSX, see the [MacTeX distribution](https://www.tug.org/mactex/).

So I went to this link and started downloading the MacTeX Download (which takes over 30 mins).

Then I read [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55438/179342) that you can use something called the TeX Live Utility on Mac.

However, when I open this app it asked me if I want to do security checks on packages so I said 'yes' and then after a long wait I get this error:

[image]

I also tried updating it this way:

```
tlmgr update --all
```

and

```
tlmgr update --self
```

both produce this error:

```
/Library/TeX/texbin/tlmgr: open tlpdb(https://ctan.mirror.rafal.ca/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb) failed: No such file or directory at /usr/local/texlive/2018/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm line 362.
```

So I guess I have 2 questions:

1. Which of the two methods is the right way to update TeX language on Mac OS X (launching the downloaded MacTex package or using Tex Live Utility)?
2. If the latter, what is the problem with my TeX Live Utility above?

Comment: Came here due to a similar update failed scenario for MacTex 2023. Ran `sudo ./tlmgr update --self` and it resolved the issue. Tex Live Utility was then able to update packages.

Answer (score 2):

I think I have solved the problem. The solution is quite obvious in retrospect:

1. From the Tex Live Utility menu select 'Check for updates' - this updated my app to the latest version (1.49). It then immediately reported that my MacTex version is out of date and opened a browser on the [MacTex download page](https://tug.org/mactex/).
2. I downloaded the latest MacTex distribution (MacTeX-2021 April) and installed the package.
3. Re-open TeX Live Utility and select the updates tab. This immediately opens a dialog saying 'Critical updates available'.  Press update button.